# Android global function and more

Tags: java, android, android-intent, global

I have pretty much 0 knowledge on android programing but willing to learn, so apart from code snippets, I would appreciate links and sources as well... That said, here is something I would like to achieve.

I am making application (well trying to) that will have multiple buttons. Those buttons will be used on various activities, but will always lead to the same activities. E.g. button1 will be part of main activity, will go to button1.activity.class but also might be present in other buttonX.activity.classes. No matter where it is it, click on it will go to button1.activity.class. Now, I would like to have global function as in I can call it from any activity in project, that would do pretty much this:
1. get tag of button (not sure if tags are used for this but this is something I have set in my head would be suitable
2. onclick will open activity with specific tag name e.g. if tag contents are "Salt" it will open SaltActivity.class.

in general I would like to have it to work like this:
openActivity(btnSalt);
where the function would look on current activity for button named (btnSalt), get string from Tag and then do something like startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Salt or whatever parameter is.class));

This should work as global so that I dont have to setup every button onClickListener in all possible activities... Im guessing creating something like Util.class then importing it to acvtivites when needed should do?

As said, code snippets, books, blogs, examples and any other help is more than appreciated.
Hope all this make some sense :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have a slight idea about Java and inheritance even though you don't know Android. You will need to let your activities inherit from a base activity.

**Option 1**

A good way to generalize that single `onClick` method you want is to define it in an Activity class, for instance `BaseActivity`, like so:

```
    public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void OnClick(View view) {
            // The generalized code here:
            String message = (String) view.getTag();
            Intent theIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ThatOneActivity.class);
            theIntent.putExtra("Your Key", message);
            startActivity(theIntent);
        }
    }
```

In the rest of your activities that will make use of this method, you just do the following:

```
public class SomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
        Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
        // We still have to add an onclicklistener to every button,
        // unless we've defined the onClick element in XML (see option 2)
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Another way to achieve the `onClick` generalization is to still have a base class that defines a method, and you add an element to the XML where you define the button:

```
android:onClick="openActivity"
```

And then you can define that method in your `BaseActivity` class, without having to add any listener to the button in the activity that implements it:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

            public void openActivity(View view) {
                // The generalized code here:
                String message = (String) view.getTag();
                Intent theIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, ThatOneActivity.class);
                theIntent.putExtra("Your_Key", message);
                startActivity(theIntent);
            }
        }
```

Eventually, in the activity that you just started (I called it `ThatOneActivity`) you can retrieve the message you added to the intent by its key:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("Your_Key");
```

Mind that hard-coding keys is asking for errors, because you might make a typo some day and it won't work anymore. The solution is simple: you pick a nice place to put a `public static final String` where you define the key (`BaseActivity` would be nice), and use that constant throughout your code.